# Get the clicked item in android list

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I have a list view in my android list activity which get data through a json file. In the list view I have to show the basic details of the item. When we click on a item I need to show more information on the item clicked. So how can I identify which item user has clicked?

Comment: where u need to show more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your listener implementation you have reference to the `View` that was clicked, and in case of `itemClick` (or ExpandableList: `groupClick` / `childClick`) you also have the position of the underlying data inside your list.

So just use the position to retrieve the clicked data from the data structure you used to populate the list (adapter).

**Update**

If you have a `ListActivity`, in which the `dataList` member holds the values you are displaying in the list, you just override it's `onListItemClick` method:

```
/**
 * The list of custom data you display in this activity
 */
private ArrayList<MyData> dataList;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final MyData selectedValue = dataList.get(position);
    //TODO: deal with this selectedValue
}
```

**API Docs** for `onListItemClick`

> This method will be called when an
>   item in the list is selected.
>   Subclasses should override.
>   Subclasses can call
>   getListView().getItemAtPosition(position)
>   if they need to access the data
>   associated with the selected item.

**Parameters**:

- `l` The ListView where the click
  happened
- `v` The view that was clicked within
  the ListView
- `position` The position of the view
  in the list
- `id` The row id of the item that was
  clicked

A complete example you can find on [Android-er here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/listactivity-and-onlistitemclick.html) and [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/implement-onlistitemclick-of.html).

Comment: can you describe it little bit more. Its great if you can give me a link to example.

Comment: i've updated my answer to contain an example, and some links, please take a look.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList;
private DataModel datamodel;
private AdapterForList adapterForList;

public ArrayList<DataModel> getArrayList(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    datamodel = new DataModel();
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        datamodel.setTextData("count"+i);
    }
    return arrayList;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    adapterForList = new AdapterForList(this,getArrayList());
    listview.setAdapter(adapterForList);
}

private class AdapterForList extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<DataModel> DataList;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    private AdapterForList(Context context,ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList){
        this.DataList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("hereeee","--->"+DataList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return DataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return DataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_view, null, true);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.lltextview = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lltextview);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textview.setText(DataList.get(position).getTextData());

        holder.lltextview.setTag(R.integer.btnview, convertView);
        holder.lltextview.setTag(R.integer.btnpos, position);
        holder.lltextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View tempview = (View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnview);
                Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag(R.integer.btnpos);

                TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText("changeee");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{

        public TextView textview;
        public LinearLayout lltextview;
    }
}
```

}