# Android playing the audio file in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, avaudioplayer

I have a listview that show all files in the folder `/diarioscolastico`

This is my code

```
public class ActivityRegistrazione extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    //Used for audio listview
    private List<String> myList;
    File file;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    //Variabile usata per usare un solo bottone come start/stop
    boolean mStartRecording = true;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {

            //Creo un file per ogni registrazione che viene fatta partire
            File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/diarioscolastico");
            mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/diarioscolastico";


            boolean success = true;
            if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                success = mFolder.mkdir();
            }
            if (success) {

                // Create an audio file name
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                String audioFileName = "AUDIO_" + timeStamp + "_.3gp";
                // Do something on success
                mFileName += "/"+ audioFileName ;

            } else {
                // Do something else on failure
            }

            startRecording();

        } else {
            stopRecording();

            //Aggiorno la listview con la nuova immagine
            //Lista con il nuovo elemento
            List<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<>();
            File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            file = new File( directory + "/diarioscolastico" );
            File list[] = file.listFiles();

            for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
            {
                myNewList.add(0,list[i].getName());
            }
                //Aggiorno la Listview dell'activity con il nuovo inserimento
                myList.clear();
                myList.addAll(myNewList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrazione);

        final Button recButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
        recButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

               onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    recButton.setText("Stop");
                } else {
                    recButton.setText("Rec");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        });

        ListView audioListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.audioList);
        myList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File( directory + "/diarioscolastico" );
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add(0, list[i].getName());
        }

        audioListView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        audioListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //TODO play the touched audio file in listview


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_registrazione, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My problem is that when i click an audio file in the listview i don't know how start some media player for listen the audio.
I found some hold stackoverflow post but they are posted in the 2010.

I found this code too:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But how can i take the uri from the listview audio file name?

There are some better ways to do this?
Can i use some intents for use the standard audioplayer?

Comment: check the answer pls

Comment: You should put File class to your ArrayAdapter as Generic Type since you need not just name of the file also path and extension and do not forget to check existence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file path from external storage, which you know and then get URI from it, thus use it to launch with standard audio player of your device

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("your file path");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks

Comment: How can i take the name of the touched row of listview?
It's possible with a adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

Comment: get the name by the arraylist(of file names/paths) index and index will be the position of row you touched(get from adapter)

Comment: are you getting file paths, ?

Comment: I need the name of touched file for testing this.
 File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 String path_audio_file = directory + "/diarioscolastico/" + touched_file ;

So i have the path

Comment: then as you know the file paths stored in arraylist can be fetched by index and your index will be the position you touched. then wha't the problem now?

Comment: onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
So the var position give me the text of the touched item? It's an int.....
So my question now is, with the arrayadapter how can i take the text of the toucheditem?
With the CustomAdapter i define my TextView and can getText() by the id.
But with the Array adapter and  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout, how i take the text?
Can you make a simple code/example please?
Thank you

Comment: simply your list: filepath= myList.get(position), in onitemclick. check linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435396/java-arrayadapter-geting-clicked-row-textview-value

Comment: Thank you very much, now i test your code and after quote checked your post, very helpfull!

Comment: @Dario, My pleasure.!