# ArrayList to have Url or when i click on a list move to another Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, arraylist

Please need a help this is my first time here to ask I hope to find my answer 
this is my java called open activity OK..

```
public class OpenMainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

        // Create a list of words
        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();


        words.add(new Word("9/10", "SmackDown ", R.drawable.smackdown));
        words.add(new Word("8/10", "Raw (Last Show)", R.drawable.rawee));
        words.add(new Word("7/10", "Super Show Down ", R.drawable.supershowdown));
        words.add(new Word("6/10", "UFC 229 FULL ", R.drawable.ufc229));
        words.add(new Word("1/10", "RAW (Last Show) ", R.drawable.rawshowlast));


        // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_listcolor);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // word_list.xml layout file.
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list1);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

And
I need to know how to get to Intent to another activity which is every list has own activity 
Or
 I need to know how to make all the list has link Url which is when I click on it moving to Google or any link such as Dailymotion for example.

Comment: read about listview.setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the clicked item in android list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853800/get-the-clicked-item-in-android-list)

Comment: you mean app activity or webpage in default web-browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an onClickListener to your listview

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   Word word = words.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(OpenMainActivity2.this, NextActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: where ?which class ? pu them where?

Comment: In the activity that you create your listview i.e. OpenMainActivity2.